# How to remove the border of a WindowsFormHost with a Forms.Control child?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm trying to remove the border of a `WindowFormsHost` that I'm using to host PDFTron's `PDFViewCtrl`.

[image]

Unfortunately, the `WindowsFormsHost` doesn't have a `BorderThickness`, or the ability to change the `WindowStyle`.

In my XAML I have the WindowsFormHost,

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="wfHost" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Loaded="wfHost_Loaded"/>
```

then later in code I set the child to be the PDFViewCtrl.

```
pdfViewCtrl = new PDFViewCtrl();
pdfViewCtrl.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
wfHost.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
wfHost.Child = pdfViewCtrl;
```

You can see more information about the PDFViewCtrl here: http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/docs/PDFNet/html/T_pdftron_PDF_PDFViewCtrl.htm

```
public class PDFViewCtrl : Control
```

where Control is a `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.

Any ideas?

Comment: WindowsFormsHost doesn't display a border unless you explicitly add one.  Which probably means that this PDFViewCtrl displays it.  It's SetPageBorderVisibility() method looks like the next thing to try, pass *false*.

Comment: Hans, the PageBorderVisibility refers to the border of the PDF document itself, not the border of the control. :(

Comment: The control doesn't appear to have anything resembling a BorderStyle property.  Ping the vendor for support.

Answer (score 0):

I use `WindowsFormsHost` in my WPF projects. It doesn't have a visible border. What you need to do is to set the hosted control's `BorderStyle` to `None`.